# Call to undefined method Illuminate\Support\Facades\Event::save()

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

Save to the database with the following code. `Event` refers to a custom model.

```
$currentEvent = new Event;

$currentEvent->end = $event['end_time'];

$currentEvent->save();
```

What's going on here - is the `save` method conflicting with something?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Event` is a kind of a reserved name in Laravel. You have two options:

1) Use a different one for your model.

2) Use namespaces.